# Facing problems in Android Studio in locating video file in the resource folder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

I am creating a video player as part of my startup project. I have made an Android Resource Directory file that I named as raw. When I locate the file in the main activity it shows an error to the following Kotlin code:

```
val uri: Uri = parse(uriString: "android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + "test" )
```

Can someone please help me with the above code because I'm getting an error?

Comment: Which error exactly? And what produces this error? Not the code you posted for sure.  I see no code. And what is the name of the file? And how are you using that urii?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the resource id of the file not the file name:

```
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(uriString: "android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.test)
```

To have cleaner code you can use this:

```
val uri = Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(packageName)
    .appendPath("${R.raw.test}")
    .build()
```